# Can't verify by visiting the external URL of the server using browser when installing apache Ranger

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, monitoring

I am installing Apache Ranger in centos by following their instructions: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/RANGER/Ranger+Installation+Guide.
But after installing and run the command:  service ranger-admin start, Ranger starts but I can't verify by visiting the external URL of the server using browser, for example: http://:6080/. I followed every instruction step by step as they said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was because of spring version. Just write the updated version of spring in pom.xml and rebuild Apache Ranger and problem is solved.